# What was Francis' plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

Near the end of [*Deadpool* (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/), Francis kidnaps Deadpool's girlfriend and holds her hostage as bait for Deadpool. ("It's a trap."). But... Deadpool is effectively invincible, and Francis knows this. So, what does Francis expect to accomplish in this battle? There is no way for him to win.

In fact, he doesn't seem to have any kind of plan at all for dealing with Deadpool and fights with him as if they were evenly matched. And since Deadpool has regeneration and Francis does not, Deadpool remains at peak strength while Francis becomes more and more broken throughout the fight. This seems to me to have been the obvious and inevitable outcome of their confrontation.

So, what did Francis intend with his "trap"? Did he really expect to be able to defeat Deadpool here somehow? What was his objective?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Earlier in the movie, Francis indicates he has a way that he thinks will kill Deadpool:

> FRANCIS: Fucking Wade Wilson. Of course, I'd wear a mask too with a face like that. I only wish I healed the same. Still. We'll put him out of our misery. On our terms.
>
> ANGEL: Right. And when he heals?
>
> FRANCIS: **He can't. Not if there's nothing left of him to heal.** You know, it's funny. I almost missed the fucker. I like a challenge. But he's bad for business. Now let's go and find him.

Presumably he's still working under that assumption and just needed Vanessa to draw him out somewhere.

Comment: I do remember that line, but it was a little unsatisfying. I wish that Francis had had a better plan. He should have been specifically attempting to incapacitate or dismember Deadpool or something. He seemed to just be fighting him with no real attempt to gain a tactical advantage despite his own severe disadvantage of not regenerating.

Answer (score -3):

Not only Ajax inteded to kill Deadpool. Deadpool was also fine with himself dying. Until the knife to the head Wade didn't know what are the limits to his healing powers.

Proof: When facing Francis Wade says

> Let's dance. And by dance I mean try to kill each other

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question of what *Francis* intended to accomplish. You've only discussed Wade's motivations.

Comment: @F1Krazy I debunked the claim that Francis didn't wanted to kill Deadpool because he knew it can't be done. Both of them assumed that the other one have to die. Ergo Francis plan was to kill Deadpool